# Trouble integrating prettyfaces with jsf

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I need to integrate [pretty faces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) with my jsf 2.0, primefaces application, but its giving some troubles.

As mentioned in the [getting started](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/#section-9) i placed following in my web.xml, added the required jar in the lib folder

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>
```

other items in my web.xml

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

But i am getting following Error:

`Invalid content was found starting with element 'async-supported'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":init-param}' is expected`

If i remove  `<async-supported>` from the project builds, project compiles but the mapping doesnt work.

`pretty-config.xml` is same as in the getting started.

Do i need to mention in my web.xml the name/path of the mapping file i.e pretty-config.xml?

**EDIT:**

I am using Glassfish server 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very important to check the `version` attribute you are using in your `web.xml`. If you have `version="2.5"` set, you have to add this to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping> 
  <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Please not that `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` is NOT set here, because it is only supported in Servlet 3.0.

If you have `version="3.0"` set in your web.xml, you don't have to add anything to your web.xml. In this case PrettyFaces automatically registers the filter using the `web-fragment.xml` that is included in `prettyfaces-jsf2.jar`.

You don't have to specify the location of `pretty-config.xml` anywhere. Just place it in your `WEB-INF` folder and PrettyFaces will find it.

You should also add one mapping to your `pretty-config.xml`, so you can check if everything works correctly. If you have for example a page that you typically access using an URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/faces/login.xhtml
```

Then you can add this mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="login">
  <pattern value="/login" />
  <view-id value="/faces/login.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Now you should be able to access the page using this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/login
```

Comment: i am using servlet version 2.5. and i think i have followed all the things that you mentioned. i will check if i missed some thing. thnx a lot! i will update/comment after trying.

Comment: In this case you added the filter correctly (without async-supported). So if you see "PrettyFilter started" on the console and have a correct pretty-config.xml in your WEB-INF, everything should work fine. :)

Comment: also, if i use pretty url, should my ManagedBeans implement`Serializable`?

Comment: Typically your managed beans are request scoped of your are using PrettyFaces. So you don't need to implement Serializable.

Comment: Was Christian's answer correct? If so, you should mark it as "accepted!" He deserves points for such a thorough answer!

Comment: +1 for the the clear and precise answer. Unfortunately, still i am facing some troubles. @Lincoln of course he does. thnx, guys for answering and commenting on my problem.